# How to add poisson noise on CT sinogram correctly in Matlab.

Tags: matlab

```
theta = linspace(0,360,900);
img = im2double(phantom(512));
figure; imshow(img)
c = radon(img, theta);
c = imnoise(c, 'poisson');
figure;imshow(c,[]);
c = iradon(c, theta);
figure; imshow(c);
```

I want to add Poisson noise to the phantom image. I do radon transform on the image and then add noise to sinogram with imnoise() and then do inverse radon transform. But I can't get correct noisy sinogram with imnoise().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's some scaling factor when using `imnoise` with poisson statistics. 
According to Matlab's documentation:

*"If I is double precision, then input pixel values are interpreted as means of Poisson distributions scaled up by 1e12. For example, if an input pixel has the value 5.5e-12, then the corresponding output pixel will be generated from a Poisson distribution with mean of 5.5 and then scaled back down by 1e12."*

try instead

```
 c = 1e12.*imnoise(c./1e12, 'poisson');
```